# .readline not printing a letter instead of a line

Tags: python-3.x, readline

keywords = open("keywords.txt", "r")

problem = input("Please give us a simple description of the problem you are having with your phone, so we can identify the solution and give it to you...")

if "screen" in problem: 
    print(keywords.readline())

elif "water" in problem: 
    print(keywords.readline(2))

elif "battery" in problem: 
    print(keywords.readline(3))

elif "dropped" in problem: 
    print(keywords.readline(4))

Answer (score 0):

`keywords.readlines()` is what you are looking for.

`keywords.readline()` is taking only one line so that if you say `keywords.readline(1)` It will return second letter in first line